# QRegExp remove line with text from QString

Tags: regex, qstring, qregexp

I would like to remove all lines from a QString that have text and keep the ones that are numbers.

Prior to running a regexp my QString output be as so:

```
hello

1

world

2
```

if I ran something like

```
QString.remove(QRegExp("(^[a-z]*\\n$)"))
```

my QString output would be:

```
1

2
```

Comment: what's the problem then? is there an error, regex not working?

Comment: Can't figure out the correct regex.

Answer (score 1):

Since `QRegExp` does not have a Perl-like `/m` modifier, you need to use groups like `(^|\n)` and `($|\n)` instead. Also, bearing in mind linebreaks may include carriage returns, I'd use something like

```
(^|\r?\n)[a-z]*\r?\n(\r?\n|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN6sB7/1)

Qt:

```
QString t = "hello\n\n1\n\nworld\n\n2";
t.replace(QRegExp("(^|\r?\n)[a-z]*\r?\n(\r?\n|$)"), "\\1");
```

**NOTE** that this code will only remove lines that only consist of lowercase ASCII letters and a linebreak after them. If you need to just remove all lines that are not numeric, use [`QRegExp("(^|\r?\n)[^\\d\n]+\r?\n(\r?\n|$)")`](https://regex101.com/r/iC8zR0/1) where `[^\d\n]` matches any non-digit character and not a newline.

Comment: I couldn't get your example to work for my needs.  I ended up just convert it to a QStringList and doing it line by line.   The only reason I wanted to do it with a regexp was to save some lines of code. Thanks for they answer.

Comment: It is always difficult to help with multiline issues as there are a lot of nuances. Glad you found a way to solve your issue.